# version.h does not show up after headers installation

Tags: software-installation, kernel, ati, catalyst

I am trying to install catalyst drivers by Radeon and I fail because `/lib/modules/3.13.0-45-generic/build/include/linux/version.h` is missing. I tried following similar questions to find that I need to install the headers and I did. Without managing to generate the required file. Below is the list of installations I did to make this work. I am running Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
sudo apt-get install gcc
sudo apt-get install lib32gcc1
sudo apt-get install dkms gcc build-essential linux-source linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright. I don't think it is supposed to show up at all. Apparently the version of catalyst I am trying to install is simply incompatible with ubuntu versions above 12.04. Which is not a problem since Gallium still supports that video driver.